# ASP.NET MVC Razor render without encoding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Razor encodes string by default. Is there any special syntax for rendering without encoding?

Answer (score 397, accepted):

Since ASP.NET MVC 3, you can use:

```
@Html.Raw(myString)
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Yes, you can insert a raw string but if you have `"'<>etc...` these will be escaped. The correct way is to use the MvcHtmlString which will allow "illegal" characters. For instance, if you're encoding Json data... without encoding an entire model

Comment: Daniel, [Html.Raw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740.aspx) "returns markup that is not HTML encoded."

Comment: Html.Raw() encodes the quotes... `"myAttr='hello';myInt=10"`

Comment: It does NOT encode quotes.  Besides the obvious documentation stating it plain as day (_"This method wraps HTML markup using the IHtmlString class, which renders **unencoded** HTML."_) I also tested this and quotes are not encoded.

Answer (score 63):

```
@(new HtmlString(myString))
```

Answer (score 36):

As well as the already mentioned @Html.Raw(string) approach, if you output an MvcHtmlString it will not be encoded. This can be useful when adding your own extensions to the HtmlHelper, or when returning a value from your view model that you know may contain html.

For example, if your view model was:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
  public string SampleString { get; set; }
  public MvcHtmlString SampleHtmlString { get; set; }
}
```

For Core 1.0+ (and MVC 5+) use HtmlString

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
  public string SampleString { get; set; }
  public HtmlString SampleHtmlString { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
<!-- this will be encoded -->
<div>@Model.SampleString</div>
<!-- this will not be encoded -->
<div>@Html.Raw(Model.SampleString)</div>
<!-- this will not be encoded either -->
<div>@Model.SampleHtmlString</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `@Html.Raw()` with caution as you may cause more trouble with encoding and security. I understand the use case as I had to do this myself, but carefully... Just avoid allowing all text through. For example only preserve/convert specific character sequences and always encode the rest:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(myString).Replace("\n", "<br/>"))
```

Then you have peace of mind that you haven't created a potential security hole and any special/foreign characters are displayed correctly in all browsers.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I needed! The string still needs to be encoded but the line returns need to be html. Thanks!

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(myString).Replace(Html.Encode("\n"), "<br/>"))` for ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 6):

In case of ActionLink, it generally uses HttpUtility.Encode on the link text.
In that case
you can use 
`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myString)` 
it worked for me when using HtmlActionLink to decode the string that I wanted to pass. eg:

```
  @Html.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("myString","ActionName",..)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the WriteLiteral method