# Actual html markup not html entity when inserted from model property in mvc3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

It probably isn't mvc3 specific but when I insert a property in my razor view

```
@Model.description
```

containing html markup

```
P><STRONG>ASSOCIATE MEMBERSHIP</STRONG><BR><BR>Individuals who are interested in being involved with the SWPRG by submitting photo's, investigation reports, attending monthly meetings, leads, stories and talking to our On-Site Team Members about cases and other issues. <BR><STRONG><EM>BENEFITS INCLUDE:</EM></STRONG><BR>-
```

the browser renders the html with HTML Entities

```
lt;P&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;ASSOCIATE MEMBERSHIP&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;BR&gt;&lt;BR&gt;Individuals who are interested in being involv
```

How do I inject the HTML to be rendered as HTML?

```
@HTML.??(@Model.description);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071602/asp-net-mvc-razor-render-without-encoding

Comment: Yes looks like a dupe. Promised I tried ;) I've voted both up though I prefer @HTML.Raw

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 @Html.Raw( Model.description );
```