# Encode String To Html Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC Razor render without encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071602/asp-net-mvc-razor-render-without-encoding)

One of the proerties of my Product object is returning a string that has html in it. When I set the model to the view, the view reads it as text and not html. How do I let the view know to read the property as html?

```
<td colspan="2">
 <div>
   <label >                             
       @Model.LongDescription  
   </label>                                 
 </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Razor encodes everything by default, you just have to use `@Html.Raw` see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071602/asp-net-mvc-razor-render-without-encoding) which is pretty much the same problem you have

```
<td colspan="2">
 <div>
   <label >                             
       Html.Raw(@Model.LongDescription)
   </label>                                 
 </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Html.Raw` helper method to ignore encoding

```
<label >                             
   @Html.Raw(Model.LongDescription)  
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HtmlString object. I prefer to handle this in my model by adding a property to the model:

```
public HtmlString LongDescription
{
    get
    {
        return new HtmlString(LongDescription);
    }
}
```

The object HtmlString will leave the html formatting in place for display.