# text rendered in partial view still encoded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have text in my database that is html encoded.

In order to display it on a normal view, I use the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071602/asp-net-mvc-razor-render-without-encoding) -

```
@Html.Raw(encodedHtmlString)
```

and it displays as expected.

However, when I do the same thing in a partial view, and then render that view with `.Partial` or `.RenderPartial`, the text is still encoded, even though the partial view renders it with @Html.Raw().

How do you prevent the parent view from encoding text rendered in a partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Partial("your view name"))
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with ASP.NET Core 2.x