# Line breaks are not rendered in MVC Razor View

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following string value generated in the controller.

```
 cc.lstchat = "Reply the Number with your question... <br />";

                foreach (clsChat item in lstchat)
                {

                    cc.lstchat =cc.lstchat + item.DisplayNumber+". " + item.ChatItem+" <br/> ";
                }
```

Now i'm trying to display above string value inside a div tag in my view but it does not render the line breaks.

```
<div id="divChat" style="width:400px;height:300px;border:double">
           @Model.lstchat.ToString()
       </div>
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor render without encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071602/asp-net-mvc-razor-render-without-encoding)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the [`@Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method

```
@Html.Raw(Model.lstchat)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Html.Raw()` it is used to render any string as HTML.

```
`@Html.Raw("input data in here is rendered as HTML only")`
```

Answer (score 2):

please please be careful with `@Html.Raw()` because of HTML injection (eg my comment will be `<script>...</script> test` - that an XSS right away. If you just want line breaks - consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4220399/1246870):

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.CommentText).Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```