# Javascript converts french special characters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, unicode-string

In my MVC 3 app I have several resx files with message strings such as: `"Editer groupe détails"`. All these are used for either window titles or confirm/alert messages. So, in order to be able to use them in my various .js files I have created in my master page a Javascript object called localizedRessources. The problem is that the strings get altered in this object, for example, the above mentioned string becomes `"Editer groupe d&#233;tails"`.

What are my options here? Is there a special function that tells JS not to encode these? Is there a way to directly use the strings in my .js files? (this works, by the way, in some cases, but i would rather I didn't have too much js code in my cshtml files).

I have the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` tag added to my `<head>` element for all pages, so I am fine there.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: use utf-8 to avoid conversion confusion

Comment: Instead of iso-8859-1?

Comment: yes, _especially_ instead of iso-8859-1. .net uses utf-16 natively, javascript utf-8, and when using PHP just save everything in UTF-8 without BOM then you will save yourself of alot of issues - with everything i mean any `.*html` `.css` `.js` etc.

Comment: I tried, no luck there.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1354491/1352471) for doing that on client side, however there should be a way to not encode it on server side, to render the real character directly. please post some code where you are rendering your localizedResources

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       /*...*/var localizedResources = {
            FailedUploadErrorMessage: '@Resources.GeneralLocalization.FailedUploadErrorMessage'/*...*/ `

Comment: ah, see [ASP.NET MVC Razor render without encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071602/asp-net-mvc-razor-render-without-encoding)

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a bunch, man! Post your last comment as an answer, so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your comment

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
/*...*/
var localizedResources = { 
   FailedUploadErrorMessage: '@Resources.GeneralLocalization.FailedUploadErrorMessage'
/*...*/
```

you tried to render javaScript using ASP.NET MVC Razor. Usually Razor escapes special characters to entities, like `&` are becoming `&amp;` non-named entities like `é` are becoming `&#233;`. In javaScript, you need these characters either native in UTF-8/16 (or if really not possible encoded like `\u00E9`).

In Razor, the `@` makes the rendering engine to output an encoded, escaped, entity-fied representation in HTML.

When rendering javaScript you don't want Razors implicit escaping, so what you need is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
/*...*/
var localizedResources = { 
   FailedUploadErrorMessage: '@Html.Raw(Resources.GeneralLocalization.FailedUploadErrorMessage)'
/*...*/
```

And oops: also [javaScript is UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141136/default-javascript-character-encoding) (with some caveats)