# Extra ampersand (amp;) is being added when Razor view is being rendered

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Razor view, which writes a javascript object:

```
var invoices = [
        @foreach (var invoice in Model.PartnerInvoices)
        {
            <text>[{ 'orderid': "@invoice.Id", 'invoiceDate': "@invoice.InvoiceDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")", 'customerName': "@invoice.CustomerName", 'customerCountry': "@invoice.CustomerCountry", 'amount': "@invoice.Amount", 'pdfLink': "@invoice.PdfUrl", 'status': "@(invoice.Status?"Sent":"Not sent")", 'accessId': "@Model.AccessToken", 'downloadPdfLink': "@invoice.DownloadPdfLink" }],</text>
        }
    ];
```

The value of `@invoice.DownloadPdfLink` is the following, when looking at in controller:

```
/partner/GetEconomicInvoice?pdfUrl=https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked/20245/pdf&token=2IuGl4j2sGKNWw1
```

Notice that between pdf and token, there is a single ampersand (&).

However, when I look at the rendered source code in my browser, I get the following output. The important difference is extra `amp;` that is being added after my ampersand.

```
 var invoices = [
            [{ 'orderid': "20244", 'invoiceDate': "15-06-2014", 'customerName': "LetterAmazer IvS", 'customerCountry': "Denmark", 'amount': "1117,00", 'pdfLink': "https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked/20244/pdf", 'status': "Not sent", 'accessId': "D-ctbWsI6dSw1", 'downloadPdfLink': "/partner/GetEconomicInvoice?pdfUrl=https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked/20244/pdf&amp;token=D-ctbWsI6dSw1" }],
            [{ 'orderid': "20245", 'invoiceDate': "15-06-2014", 'customerName': "Holtron v. Ib Holdgaard", 'customerCountry': "Denmark", 'amount': "219,00", 'pdfLink': "https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked/20245/pdf", 'status': "Not sent", 'accessId': "D-ctbWsI6dSw1", 'downloadPdfLink': "/partner/GetEconomicInvoice?pdfUrl=https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked/20245/pdf&amp;token=D-ctbWsI6dSw1" }],
            [{ 'orderid': "20243", 'invoiceDate': "01-06-2014", 'customerName': "Datahouse Ltd.", 'customerCountry': "Data Country", 'amount': "767,00", 'pdfLink': "https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked/20243/pdf", 'status': "Sent", 'accessId': "D-ctbWsI6dSw1", 'downloadPdfLink': "/partner/GetEconomicInvoice?pdfUrl=https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked/20243/pdf&amp;token=D-ctbWsI6dSw1" }],
    ];
```

How on earth is this extra amp; being added? And how to solve it?

I have tried to UrlEncode/UrlDecode without luck. The amperstand is still being added.

Comment: `&amp;` is the HTML encoded version of `&`.

Comment: Yes, I know. That doesn't explain why there is being added an extra &amp; in addition to my &

Comment: It isn't added to your existing path; it is *replacing* your `&` as far as I see. Therefore the solution will have something to do with the encoding of your url. I don't know how to solve it myself but I was merely pointing out that nothing is being added but instead being replaced.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel haha, omg, you are right.. i am so ****ing stupid. Thanks - actually solves the problem

Comment: Use `Html.Raw` like so: `@Html.Raw(invoice.DownloadPdfLink)`

Comment: Yep. A link for Googlers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071602/asp-net-mvc-razor-render-without-encoding